# NullPointerException when using registerForActivityResult Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, sdk

I'm trying to sign with google using pianoID I have called registerForActivityResult method from flutter but it returns a null pointer.

I tested it in a native android application and it works perfectly it shows me a google login popup.

this is my code :

```
final ActivityResultLauncher<PianoIdClient.SignInContext> authResult = registerForActivityResult(
            new PianoIdAuthResultContract(),
            r -> {
                if (r == null) {
                    System.out.println("this is r");
                } else if (r.isSuccess()) {
                    PianoIdAuthSuccessResult data = (PianoIdAuthSuccessResult) r;
                    boolean isNewUserRegistered = data.isNewUser();
                    PianoIdToken token = data.getToken();
                    if (token.emailConfirmationRequired) {
                    }
                } else {
                    PianoIdAuthFailureResult data = (PianoIdAuthFailureResult) r;
                    PianoIdException e = data.getException();
                }
            }
    );
```

Invoke methode :

```
if (call.method.equals("signInTest")){
        authResult.launch( PianoId.signIn().widget(PianoId.WIDGET_LOGIN));
    }
```

here I call it in flutter :

```
await bridgeToNative.invokeMethod('signInTest');
```

and this is the exception :

> E/MethodChannel#flutter.native/helper(27553): Failed to handle method call
> E/MethodChannel#flutter.native/helper(27553): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
> E/MethodChannel#flutter.native/helper(27553):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5378)
> E/MethodChannel#flutter.native/helper(27553):   at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:647)